# Any good Graduate Level linear algebra textbook for practice/problem solving?

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, book-recommendation

I am looking for good graduate linear algebra books that contain practice problems with solutions (which is better) or hints to solve the problems. By the way, two graduate courses I am gonna take are a continuation of the undergrad course I have already taken based on the textbook: "Linear Algebra: A modern Approach" by "D.Poole". I did find some textbooks that cover the material, like: "Linear Algebra done right", "Linear Algebra done wrong", etc and some of these books suggest few problems without given solutions. So, I need books with many solved problems (or hints) that help me to practice what I will learn in the lecture and to ensure I well understand the material. Any suggestion is more than welcome. Thanks

Comment: Graduate? Hmm... well, perhaps you should look at abstract algebra books. Dummit & Foot, "Abstract Algebra" is good. Lang's "Algebra" is rather dense, and is not for the faint of heart, but if you're adventurous enough (or after reading a softer introduction first), it is excellent for its rigor and hard problems (I remember studying that for my Algebra qualifying exam).

Comment: Halmos's *Linear algebra problem book* is worth checking out.

Comment: I like Hefferon, http://joshua.smcvt.edu/linearalgebra/ , and it has the advantage that it's free. The answers to the exercises are available.

Comment: As for practice problems, I'm not sure, but I have a special place in my heart for [Curtis' Abstract Linear Algebra](http://books.google.com/books?id=DJqqOLdKQpwC&printsec=frontcover&dq=abstract+linear+algebra&hl=en&sa=X&ei=KhEKT4OsM6ro0QGjrojRAg&ved=0CEIQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=abstract%20linear%20algebra&f=false). It's a tiny little book which is so easy to read.

Comment: Also Viktor Prasolov, " Problems and theorems in linear algebra "

Comment: I always thought "Graduate Linear Algebra = Functional Analysis"...

Comment: Many variations of this question have been asked here before: http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Breference-request%5D+Linear+Algebra

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a book by Jonathan Golan called *The Linear Algebra a Beginning Graduate Student Ought to Know*. I would take look at that. It has tons of pretty good problems.

Comment: This is a great book. May I know where to find it’s solution manual?

Answer (score 11):

In [Berkeley Problems in Mathematics](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/analysis/book/978-0-387-20429-1) book, there are a lot of problems with solutions of Linear Algebra as well as Analysis and Algebra. The problems are taken from [Preliminary Exams of UC Berkeley](http://math.berkeley.edu/programs/graduate/prelim-exams/archive).

Answer (score 7):

I would like to recommend "Linear algebra: challenging problems for students" by Fuzhen Zhang

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the Halmos book already mentioned, which is indeed excellent, there are several other problem books/solution manuals for theoretical linear algebra:

1. Shakarchi's [Solution Manual to Lang's Linear Algebra](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387947604)
2. Blythe's [Algebra Through Practice: Matrices and Vector Spaces](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521272866) and [Algebra Through Practice: Linear Algebra](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521272890)
3. Don't overlook [Schaum's outline of linear algebra](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/007154352X). There are some good problems in there as well

Also, I would find it somewhat surprising if you couldn't find solutions to many of Axler's problems on-line.

**Added:**

One very good sources of problems/solutions that I neglected to mention is UC Denver's archive of past Applied Linear Algebra qualifying exams (with solutions) found here: [Qualifying Exams](http://www.ucdenver.edu/academics/colleges/CLAS/Departments/math/program_info/phd/prelims/Pages/PreliminaryExams.aspx). Don't be misled by the adjective "applied"; these problems are theoretical in nature and a similar to those found in Axler (though perhaps a little more demanding, but not by much)

Answer (score 2):

the Halmos book and Blythe's book are good reference but it is elementary book in linear algebra.I suggest you [Linear Algebra](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0130084514) by Stephen H. Friedberg or [Problems and Theorems in Linear Algebra](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0821802364) by V. V. Prasolov

Comment: I would argue that the books by both Blythe and Halmos are roughly on the same level as the Axler text to which the OP refers.

Comment: Recently new Russian edition of Prasolov's books has been published. It has now a much more content. So if you know Russian you must purchase new second edition of the book.

Answer (score 1):

Linear Algebra Done Right is a key text at Harvard, MIT, and Berkeley. So, despite some attitude issues (starting with the title) it might be worthwhile to give it your fullest consideration.

Here is a link to course materials generously made available at MIT which has all you need, including a set of great lecture beamers.

http://math.mit.edu/~trasched/18.700.f11/index.html

Answer (score 0):

My favorite linear algebra book is "Linear Algebra" by Hoffman and Kunze.  I absolutely love it, and recommend it.

Comment: Does this book contain problems with solutions really?

Comment: It has numerous worked examples, and problem sets to go along with them... If you mean a solutions manual I don't know...