# Where are the resources for a collection of linear algebra problems?

Tags: linear-algebra

Are there any resources consisting of a collection of problems on linear algebra for students to practice? I am looking for good interesting problems which test students’ understanding. These questions or examples should be for teaching rather than just testing. The level of difficulty is first year undergraduate.

Comment: You mean beside the felt 1000 books which are intentend to get bought by students panicking at exams ?

Comment: It is a good idea you browse some of the questions here (math.stackexchange) which are tagged linear algebra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for graduate level (doesn't sound like it), you can look at this [*MSE answer*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97435/any-good-linear-algebra-textbook-for-practice-problem-solving?rq=1).

For undergraduate, there are several book recommendations:

- - 3,000 Solved Problems in Linear Algebra by Seymour Lipschutz
  - Schaum's Outline of Linear Algebra, 5th Edition (Schaum's Outlines) Seymour Lipschutz, Marc Lipson
  - Linear Algebra: Challenging Problems for Students (Johns Hopkins Studies in the Mathematical Sciences) by Fuzhen Zhang (Author)
  - Linear Algebra Problem Solver (REA) The Editors of REA (Author)
  - [*Elementary Linear Algebra - K. Matthews*](http://www.numbertheory.org/book/), which is free.
  - Too many other books to list (the ones above are probably what you are looking for and very good prices).
- Other MSE book requests links (see right pane of this page) and search for those.

Additional ideas:

- Open Courseware at places like [*MIT*](http://ocw.mit.edu/index.htm) and other international universities (lectures and notes).
- Browse your college library and look through the books and see if there are other examples that fit the style of writing/examples/problems you like.
- The linear algebra area of [*Khan Academy*](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra).

Comment: Very nice collection! +1